# Let $X$ and $Y$ be of the same dimension and jointly normal. Find the distribution of $X+Y$.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be of the same dimension and jointly normal. Find the distribution of $X+Y$.

Can we start off by saying that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, then $X$ and $Y$ are normal as well?, i.e.:
$$X=AZ_X+\mu_X$$
$$Y=BZ_Y+\mu_Y$$

Comment: To clarify: are $X$ and $Y$ *multivariate* normal or univariate normal?

Comment: That is the source of my confusion, In the answer sheet to this question, the answer starts with what I have written here, but that would imply both are multivariate normal, right?

Comment: That would make sense, especially since you're talking about the "dimension" of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: And then if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly multivariate normal, $X$ and $Y$ alone are also multivariate normal. Is that correct?

Comment: They are normal ("same dimension") and yes, $X+Y$ is normal with mean $E(X)+E(Y)$ and covariance $\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y+cov(X,Y)+cov(Y,X)$.

Comment: @Clari I'm liberally interpreting $cov(X,Y)$ as $E(XY^t)-E(E(X)E(Y^t))$.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate your help.

Comment: See my answer below. Once you show $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are individually normal, it's easy to show that $\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}$ is normal.

Comment: @Clari But you need joint normality, not individual normality.

Comment: @A.S. Since $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y}$ are jointly normal (as given in the question), you can use the answer below to show that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are individually normal, and so forth...

Comment: @Clari Of course, but WHY would you want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are separately normal is it's not enough to ensure normality of $X+Y$?

Comment: @A.S. Then I can just say that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]=\mu_X+\mu_Y$ and $X+Y=I_n(X,Y)^T \implies \sum_{X+Y}=I_n^T\sum_{(X,Y)^T}I_n=\sum_X+\sum_{YX}+\sum_{XY}+\sum_{Y}$. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't see how $I_n$ comes into play, but the end result is correct. Note that $cov(X,Y)=cov(Y,X)^t$.

Comment: @A.S. Could you tell me how to do it properly?

Comment: $cov(X+Y)=cov(X)+cov(Y)+cov(X,Y)+cov(Y,X)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Conflicting_nomenclatures_and_notations for definition/properties of covariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the method you're using up there, but here's how I would pursue this problem.

**Hint**. Suppose $$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X} \\
\mathbf{Y}
\end{bmatrix}\sim\mathcal{N}_{2p}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \mathbf{V})$$ 
($p$ being the dimension of both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$).

A very well-known theorem is the following:

**Theorem**. Any subvector of a multivariate normal vector is also (multivariate) normal.

It follows immediately from this theorem that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ must both be normal.

*Sketch of proof*. Let's suppose $\mathbf{W} \sim \mathcal{N}_k(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\mathbf{W}}, \mathbf{V}_\mathbf{W})$. Perform induction on the size of the subvector of $\mathbf{W}$, say $m \leq k$.

If we have a subvector of $\mathbf{W}$ with $m = 1$, *by definition of a multivariate normal*, every subvector of length $1$ of $\mathbf{W}$ must be multivariate normal.

Now try completing this proof.